# How to destroy all records for a table including :dependent records in other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console

What is the best way to do this on Heroku? through the console? I do have 'dependent: :destroy' set for all the dependent tables.

Comment: Of course. I was waiting to try it first. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
heroku run rails console

> Model.destroy_all
```

The Model is the name of the model you want to destroy

Answer (score 5):

You may use:

```
Object.delete_all
```

you can also set the :dependent option to :delete_all. :delete_all will issue a single SQL statement to delete all child records. because of this using :delete_all may give you better performance.

```
has_many :childs, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Comment: .destroy_all will delete dependent: :destroy objects

.delete_all will not delete dependent: :destroy objects